# Fluent nhibernate map lookup table as enum

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I am trying to map a lookup table to an enum using: 
FluentNhibernate 1.3.0.733
NHibernate 3.3.1.4000

I am not able to load objects. If I remove the enum mapping I can load objects.

Code:

```
Order order = session.Get<Order>(id);
```

Error:
Provided id of the wrong type. Expected: Order+OrderStatus, got System.Int32

Object:

```
public class Order
{
    public enum OrderStatus
    {
        PaymentPending = 0
    }

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
    public virtual OrderStatus Status { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public Order()
    {
        OrderLines = new List<OrderLine>();
    }
}
```

Mapping: (I have cut the mapping down to these fields for testing)

```
public OrderMapping()
{
    Table("orders");
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Id(x => x.Status, "state_id").CustomType<Order.OrderStatus>().Not.Nullable();
    References(x => x.Address).Cascade.All().Column("address_id");
    References(x => x.Customer).Cascade.All().Column("customer_id");
}
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [order_states] (
    [id] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [state] NVARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [orders] (
    [id] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [customer_id] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    [address_id] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    [state_id] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    [created] DATE,

    FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) REFERENCES customers(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(address_id) REFERENCES addresses(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(state_id) REFERENCES order_states(id)
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are mapping OrderStatus as an Id, not as a property. And as far as i know, CustomType should be int, not Order.OrderStatus.

Comment: You are correct, I should be mapping that as a property, not an id.

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek CustomeType should indeed be the enum type (this will give you integers in the database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caused by a silly error.
I had the the status mapped as an id and not as a property.

Correct mapping:

```
public OrderMapping()
        {
            Table("orders");
            Id(x => x.Id);
            Map(x => x.Status, "state_id").CustomType<Order.OrderStatus>().Not.Nullable();
            References(x => x.Address).Cascade.All().Column("address_id");
            References(x => x.Customer).Cascade.All().Column("customer_id");
        }
```